# How to configure webpack-spritesmith with Webpack Encore?

Tags: php, symfony, webpack-encore

I'm working on a Symfony 3.4 project and I use Webpack Encore to manage my assets. Until then it works fine.

I'd like to use [webpack-spritesmith](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-spritesmith) package to build an image sprite.
But when I run `yarn encore dev` command, I face the error:

```
{ Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read errno: -21, code: 'EISDIR', syscall: 'read' }
```

Here is my project's structure:

```
/
|-assets
| |-js
| | |-app.js
| | ...
| |-images
| | |-new.png
| | |-open.png
| | |-save.png
| | |-sprites
| | | |-foo.png
| | | |-bar.png
| | | ...
| | ...
| |-scss
| | |-app.scss
| | ...
| ...
|-web
| |-build
| ...
|-webpack.config.js
```

I followed the documentation of the package to configure it but I'm not sure how to do with Symfony Encore overlay.

Here is my `webpack.config.js` file:

```js
let Encore            = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');
let SpritesmithPlugin = require('webpack-spritesmith');
let path              = require('path');

Encore
    .setOutputPath('web/build/')
    .setPublicPath('/build')
    .addEntry('app', './assets/js/app.js')
    .enableSingleRuntimeChunk()
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())
    .enableBuildNotifications()
    .enableSassLoader()
    .enablePostCssLoader()
    .addLoader({
        test: /\.png$/,
        use: ['file-loader?name=images/[hash].[ext]']
    })
    .autoProvidejQuery()
    .addPlugin(new SpritesmithPlugin({
        src:        {
            cwd:  path.resolve(__dirname, './assets/images/sprites'),
            glob: '*.png'
        },
        target:     {
            image: path.resolve(__dirname, './assets/images/sprite.png'),
            css:   path.resolve(__dirname, './assets/scss/sprite.scss')
        },
        apiOptions: {
            cssImageRef: "~sprite.png"
        }
    }));

let config = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
config.resolve = {
    modules: ["node_modules", "./assets/images"]
};

module.exports = config;
```

I expect files to be generated as following:

- /assets/images/sprite.png
- /assets/scss/sprite.scss

Neither the `sprite.png` nor the `sprite.scss` file is created. However, some PNGs are generated in `web/buid/images` dir with hashed name.

Comment: The problem seems to be caused by sub-directories in my `assets/images/sprites` dir.
There is an issue opened on github about this : https://github.com/mixtur/webpack-spritesmith/issues/83

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a [reported issue](https://github.com/mixtur/webpack-spritesmith/issues/83) that has been closed since.

Note that sub-directories are now simply ignored, so keep all your images in a same directory.